# Why we target to minimize Cross Entropy in classification problem in Deep neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am reading about why cross-entropy is the widely used as loss function in deep neural network for classification problems.

As per my understanding, cross entropy compares two probability distributions and if both distributions(Target and predicted) are same then cross entropy will be same as entropy.

formulas are as follows:

```
entropy =  Summataion of i=0 to n for  p(X)x log(p(X))
cross entropy = Summataion of i=0 to n for p(X) x log(q(X))

p(x) --> probabilty distribution of target values
q(x) --> probabilty distribution of predicted values
```

Why we target to minimize the value of cross entropy then how will it learn the probability distribution of actual values?

Comment: It just an entropy. For a 4 class output for example, [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25] has more entropy than [0.9, 0.025, 0.025, 0.05]. So you are forcing the network to learn one class (possibly the true class) by penalising to distribute the probabilities equally (giving large cost(entropy)).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But still I have one doubt. Lets assume 3 classes are there and the probability of each class is as follows [0.2, 0.3, 0.5] (entropy = 0.44) and the model predicted probailities are [0.3, 0.4, 0.3]. After calculating cross entropy will be 0.3777. It looks good because it is lesser thn entropy and SGD will try to further reduce it. But to have the same distribution here shall we not focus to increase cross entropy until it reaches entropy value.

Comment: Regarding "the probability of each class is as follows [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]", you. have the ground truth for the given image [1, 0, 0] and the network predicts [0.3, 0.4, 0.3] (as you said), the loss is just penalising that. You do not compare with the probability of each class, you compare with the ground truth. The network gives you the probability of the given image belongs to each class separately.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have understood. Same thing is clearly explained in this blog as well. https://medium.com/unpackai/cross-entropy-loss-in-ml-d9f22fc11fe0

Comment: Please note that this is not a programming issue and is off-topic in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score -1):

Lets forget about cross entropy and instead start by saying

> "I want to maximise the probability that all my predictions `p` match
> targets `y`"

Now maximising probability and its logarithm is the same, so lets do it for computational simplicity so we don't have to multiply a lot of numbers smaller than one (which could lead to super tiny numbers of underflows). For simplicity lets do this for just binary case, but multi-class works the same way.

```
log PROD_i P(p_i=y_i) = SUM_i log P(p_i=y_i) 
                      = SUM_i [y_i * log P(p_i=1) + (1-y_i) log P(p_i = 0)]
                      = SUM_i [y_i * log P(p_i=1) + (1-y_i) log (1-P(p_i = 1))]
                      = -CE( y || p )
```

The crucial transformation happened when we noticed that `log P(p_i=1)` is either equal to `log P(p_i=1)` is `y_i` was 1, or `log P(p_i=0)` when it was 0 (and thus equivalent to multiplying by `1-y_i`).

Comment: Given your reputation, you should know that is is bad practice to answer off-topic questions.

Comment: I am here to help people, not to be policing around; If I can help before the question gets closed, I choose to do so.

Comment: If you want to help people about general ML/AI questions, you can go to ai.stackexchange.com/ or stats.stackexchange.com/ , these sites have plenty of unanswered questions. You are not actually helping people if questions will be closed anyways.

Comment: You are aware closed questions are still possible to read, answers are still correct and people are being helped right?

Comment: That is irrelevant, if your answer is wrong, people cannot post a new answer, if your answer is no longer correct, the same. We have multiple dedicated sites, with your attitude you are only telling other answerers to go somewhere else, and not telling people we have sited dedicated to their non-programming topics which usually struggle to get good questions. Stack Overflow might be the most well known of SE sites, but that does not mean all questions should go here. Why not answer cooking or politics questions too?